Upgrade windows server 2012 to windows server 2016
I am trying to upgrade Server 2012 to Server 2016, Keep Personal Files and Folders option is Disabled.
I buy licence and tried to install iso file that they sent me and also download from Microsoft. Windows Server 2016 | Microsoft Evaluation Center. language on running Windows 2012 and 2016 I am tryng to instal are the same. what is solution in this case?
